# Installing ordinary differential equation package

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trouble installing `odeint`

i tried

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
```

and received this error message:

> 'from' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

How should i successfully install this so i can use `odeint`?

Comment: You have to enter that Python statement in a Python shell, not in a Windows terminal.

Comment: if you are running a file, try running the file via python `python myfile.py`

Comment: I tired it in the idle window and got an error of 'no module named scipy'